# Strange PHP compiler error when using closure

Tags: php

What wrong with the following code?

WHen I tried to run the linter, it give me:

```
# PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in test.ph on line 19

<?php

   function foo()
    {

        return function() 

        {
            print 'bar';
        }    
    }
```

Comment: You need php 5.3+ to use closures

Comment: That code is invalid even in PHP/5.4. He's missing a semicollon, as @Korikulum points out.

Comment: all the same, it would have been useful if the question had specified the PHP version in use, given the number of PHP installations out there on versions that don't support closures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [return](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php) [expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php) needs to end and have a correct syntax.

```
// correct syntax
return EXPRESION;

// your function
function foo()
{
    return function()
    {
        print 'bar';
    }; // You need to add a semicolon.
}
```